# How do I get a node, or a taxonomy term URL knowing the node ID or the taxonomy term ID?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I need to render the full URL from a taxonomy term ID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The generic way is this:

```
$uri = entity_uri($entity_type, $entity);
$url = $uri['path'];
```

So for a node, `$entity_type` would be 'node', and `$entity` would be the fully loaded node object.

Taxonomy terms are also entities in D7, so the syntax would be similar.

Comment: In the case of a taxonomy term, `$entity_type` must be set to `"taxonomy_term"`.